Fast Endpoints DontCatchExceptions(); not working
I am using Fast Endpoints in a .net8 Blazor Web App API.  I am putting
DontCatchExceptions();

in some of the Configure methods like this:
Post("policies/contacts");
Options(x => x.WithTags("Policy"));
DontCatchExceptions();

and the HandleAsync method throws the error:'
  public override async Task HandleAsync(CancellationToken ct)
  {
    try
    {
      var list = await Data.GetCountryCodeList();

      await SendAsync(list);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      ThrowError(e.Message, 400);
    }
  }

So far I've only use it in GET methods and it's worked fine.  Now I'm using it in a POST method, but it doesn't work. It's just ignored - no error or anything.  I don't know if it's because it's a POST method, that's just the only obvious difference I see. I put a breakpoint on the ThrowError line and it's hitting there.

I left this for a while and came back.  I reinstalled the nuget package and it worked.  I hate when that happens!  Sending the response to the client is what I was trying to do.
Thank you

you have misunderstood the purpose of ThrowError() method i believe.

ThrowError() - This method will abort execution immediately and send an error response to the client.

even though this method starts with Throw..., it doesn't actually throw exceptions in the traditional sense. it's purpose is to shortcircuit execution of the handler and send an error response.
that would've worked normally. it doesn't work because you're turning off the built-in error response functionality with the use of DontCatchExceptions(), which is what you'd be doing if you had your own exception catching middleware setup.
